# Index and Match with Multiple Results and concatenate

Tags: excel-formula

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBgLP.jpg) I have a large amount of data where I usually use an index and match formula.
It always brings the first result. Is it possible if it can bring multiple results from the same column and concatenating the result with a single space?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible Solution would be this **ARRAY-FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D2,$A$1:$A$7)),ROW($D$1:$D$7)),COLUMNS($E$1:E1))),"")
```

This formula needs to be pulled downwards and sideways. Multiple results will be listed columnwise.

[image]

Concatenating is a bit of a problem in earlier EXCEL versions. If you have Office 2019 or Office 365, you could use `Textjoin`.